# How do I fix a peeling shower floor?

Tags: shower

What is the thin plastic sheet called on the shower floor. Mine is starting to peel up and water is getting underneath it. Is it replaceable? It seems the plastic layer has ruined the real floor of the shower from water sitting underneath it so often. Is that replaceable? It’s the material that gives it the marble look. Kind of like peeling off a big sticker.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If Ecnerwal's suggestion isn't the case, this looks like a tear-out-and-replace situation. The panels are delaminating, and you don't fix something like that in a wet application.

It's also likely that the substrate will need some repair or complete replacement if water has been leaking. Plan, design, save, then go to it.

Answer (score 0):

What that looks like is a protective plastic sheet so the surface of the stone or faux-stone didn't get scratched in shipping and handling that should have been removed at install time.

If (as it seems) it wasn't removed before caulking, you probably need to remove it and then redo the caulking. You don't need to replace it.

Comment: I thought so too, at first, but it looks more like the actual finish layer with color.